# Using custom LaTeX class changes numbering in R Markdown

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr

I recently discovered that you can include your own LaTeX class in an R-Markdown doc to change the appearance of the PDF. Here is a minimal example:

### R Markdown

```
---
title: "Test"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
documentclass: book
output:
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: natbib
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
fontsize: 12pt
--- 

# A
## AA
### AAA
### AAA
## AB
# B
```

This works as intended.

[image]

But when I define my own class, the numbering is preceded by 0s and the page numbering is off.

### myclass.cls

I place a file called "myclass.cls" in the same direcoty as the RMD file above and change `documentclass: myclass`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProvidesClass{glasgowthesis}

\LoadClass{book}
```

My understanding is that this should simply call the same class as above but the file now looks like this:

[image]

Maybe somebody can give me a hint what I'm doing wrong. I would like to copy the book class 1:1 before starting to change things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution in the [bookdown book](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/theming.html) and wanted to share it in case anyone wanders off to this question through google etc.

> Note that when you change documentclass, you are likely to specify an
>   additional Pandoc argument --top-level-division=chapter so that Pandoc
>   knows the first-level headers should be treated as chapters instead of
>   sections (this is the default when documentclass is book)

So this YAML header solved the issue:

```
---
title: "Test"
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%d %B, %Y')`"
documentclass: myclass
output:
  pdf_document:
    pandoc_args: --top-level-division=chapter
    citation_package: natbib
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 3
    number_sections: true
fontsize: 12pt
--- 

# A
## AA
### AAA
### AAA
## AB
# B
```